# plot_text horizontal and vertical alignment equivalent in bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

Is there an equivalent of matplotlib's ha and va (horizontal and vertical alignment) when plotting text in bokeh?

In matplotlib I would write something like the following:

```
plt.text(x, y, 'text', ha='center', va='bottom')
```

In bokeh I am plotting text using the following method:

```
glyph = Text(x="x", y="y", text="text")
stagger_data.add_glyph(source, glyph)
```

Where source is a ColumnDataSource object.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the text_align and the text_baseline attributes of the Text glyph.

```
glyph = Text(x="x", y="y", text="text", text_align="center",text_baseline="bottom")
```

You can have a look [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/text.html#bokeh.models.Text)  in the documentation to see all the available fields in the creation of a Text glyph.